# Get posts from WP_Query and format them on admin_head

Tags: plugins, wp-query, actions

I am trying to prepare an array with Custom Post Type posts to populate a select options in TinyMCE.

I was thinking to fetch posts, get their IDs and titles and put them all inside `$data` variable, which I would like to send to TinyMCE with `wp_localize_script`. The problem with this code is that it doesn't load. It seems like I can't call `WP_Query` nor use `if(myquery->have_posts()` or `while(myquery->have_posts())`, the page takes too long to complete and I get  `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`. 
Currently I have only 2 posts in CTP for testing and getting data should be fast.

I am doing this by creating a class inside plugin.

```
public function __construct()       {
        add_action('admin_head', array($this, 'prepare_for_tinymce'));
        //add_action('admin_head', array($this, 'gavickpro_add_my_tc_button'));
    }


    public function prepare_for_tinymce(){

        wp_register_script('literatura_reference_js', plugins_url('tinymce.js', __FILE__ ), array( ), 1.0, true );

        // get custom data from WP_QUERY - THIS DOESN'T WORK
        $data = $this->pl_get_books();

    /*     $data = array(   array(
    *           'id' => 1,
    *           'title' => 'asfsdf'
    *           ) );
    */      

        // send data to javascript - THIS WORKS OK (I have tried with $data array above)
        wp_localize_script( 'literatura_reference_js', 'literatura_tinymce', $data );
        wp_enqueue_script('literatura_reference_js');


    }


    // get data from custom post type
    public function pl_get_books(){

        $myquery= new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'knjige',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
                ));

        $data = array();
        if($myquery->have_posts()) :
            while($myquery->have_posts()) :
                $data[] = array(
                    'id' => get_the_ID(),
                    'title' => get_the_title()
                    );
            endwhile;
            endif; 
            wp_reset_query(); 
            return $data;

        }
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing `$myquery->the_post();` inside your while loop.

I think `get_the_ID()` and `get_the_title()` depend on that being setup first.

Also, `wp_reset_query();` should be replaced with `wp_reset_postdata();`.

Comment: and `while($myquery->have_posts())` will also never be false, it's an infinite loop.

Comment: That solved my problem, although I still couldn't make it work with WP_Query for some reason, but it works with get_posts :)